# Running python script from terminal without .py extension

Tags: command-line, python, filenames, executable

I want to call a python script *script.py* from the terminal by simply typing *script*. Is this possible? If so, how?

I know I can avoid typing *python script.py* by adding *#!/usr/bin/env python* to the top of the script, but I still have to add the suffix *.py* in order to run the script.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unix/Linux file systems do not rely on extensions the way windows does. You should not need the `.py` at the end of a file to run it.

You can run the file by either calling it with the interpreter:

```
python ScriptFile
```

Or by marking it executable and defining the interpreter on the first line (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python`).

If you are unable to execute the file with:

```
/Path/to/ScriptFile
```

check the permissions with

```
ls -l ScriptFile
```

You may need to add the executable flag and `chmod` it so it will execute for you.

If you are using custom scripts regularly you may want to make sure the directory you store them is added to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The file is in ~/workspace/python. I've added ~/workspace/python to my path, I ran *sudo chmod a+x script.py", and I've added the shebang line (#!/usr/bin/env python) to the top of the script.

I can run the script by typing *script.py*, but just typing *script* doesn't work.

Comment: In unix/linux everything is a file and responds to its file name.

You can not call Script.py as script.
Try renaming the file from script.py to script and it should fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood! Everything solved, thanks!

Comment: linux does depend on file extensions pretty much like windows does. Many things break if one adds a (wrong) extension or removes it from files, although not from all, which is similar to the situation on windows. Many files additionally or instead encode the content type within the file, but that also applies to windows.

Answer (score 6):

The `.py` extension is unnecessary for running the script. You only have to make the script executable (e.g. by running `chmod a+x script`) and add the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env python`).

Comment: See my comment on Patrick's reply.

Answer (score 5):

As an option you could create wrapper for your script (a `.py` file):

For example, you have a script `runme.py` so you can create new file `runme` to wrap the script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import runme
```

and then call the `runme.py` functionality just by invoking `runme` in the shell.

That is useful for multiplatform scripts, cause on Windows platform you can assign `.py` files to be invoked just by name without extension and *shebang* in the header, but on the linux platform you can't and thus the wrapper comes out.